# can some one please explain about error in css called dots-per-CSS-inch & not dots-per-physical-inch

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, dpi

I am working in ubntu and i use mi mobile to for remote debuging i am getting the below one in blue color i am not sure it is an error.

while remote debugging i am getting this error:

```
 Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, (min-resolution: 144dpi), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)
```

I think this error occurs due to quality purpose but i am not understaing about dppx and dpi and please help me if you know solution for this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a follow up, this was an [ERROR](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336276).

**Solution:**

If you have dppx override, it should not show you this message anymore.

Please find the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/9k1y1srf/2/) for testing.

**CODE:**

```
  @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
    only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 

      /* Retina-specific stuff here */

  }
```

Comment: Sorry, can I have some more detailed explanation abut fiddle and about the code you answered me and In which file i should override dppx, thanks